# 7z is not excluding directories from exclude file

Tags: shell-script, 7z

In a bash script I want to create an archive with 7z and exclude some directories. I created an exclude file that only contains one entry:

```
excl_dir/
```

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
archiveName="my_archive"
base="/path/to/base"

7z a -mx=9 -t7z -xr@exclude.lst "${archiveName}.7z" "${base}/files/*"
```

The archive gets created but with the directory from the exclude file.

Things I considered:

- The exclude file is UTF-8 encoded
- The exclude file is in the same directory as my script
- I tried absolute and relative paths (i.e. `/path/to/exclude.lst` and `./exclude.lst`)
- exclude file format: `excl_dir/`, `excl_dir/*`, newline after the entry

Is the entry in the exclude file correct? When yes, what else could be wrong?

**Edit:**

When the entry in exclude.lst is just `excl_dir`, 7z actually excludes this folder. But also every file that has this string in it's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `7z` can only exclude patterns and ignores trailing slashes. As a workaround, instead of excluding, pass it a list of the files you want to include:

```
find . -not -path './excl_dir/*' -not -path './excl_dir' > /tmp/include.lst
7z a -mx=9 -t7z -i@/tmp/include.lst foo.7z
```

This seems like a bug in `7z`.

Comment: @don_crissti hmm. Might be a fixed bug then. On my system (v 9.20) `./bar/` in the exclude file also matched the file `./barr`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then... I couldn't find any relevant entry in the [changelogs](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt) as Igor has the bad habit of simply writing _"Some bugs were fixed"_...

Comment: I also have the version 9.20 on the system, so unfortunately I have to use the workaround.
Thanks for that.